# Can't switch keyboard layout in all Qt5 applications

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, gnome

I use **elementary OS Loki** based on Ubuntu 16.04.2

I have **Qt5** installed in `/opt/Qt/` (is it a native and correct place, by the way? or there is a better one?)

To have it recognized by apps, I've created the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/qt5.conf` file, which contains the `"/opt/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib"` string.

I use TeXstudio to write in Russian and I always need two layouts: ru and en. But **TeXstudio**, **Neovim-Qt** and even **Qt Creator** does not react on layout switch and always remain with the layout that was enabled on an app startap. I found several tickets for GNOME and Qt5 with this issue, but they were closed back in 2014...

What kind of problem I face? To be honest, when I used a very old Qt and a very old texstudio form ubuntu repositories, everything worked fine. But I needed a fresh **Qt5** for **Neovim-Qt** and after adding the `"/etc/ld.so.conf.d/qt5.conf"` file (which points the system to the new Qt5), I faced the described bug.

I also notice a pretty strange behavior: If I switch the layout and type a letter immideately, sometimes it goes in the new layout, but the second and further letters are in the old one...

What can I do with it?

Comment: I could not live with it so I commented out the string in `ld.so.conf.d` and built nvim-qt with the `RPATH`. TeXstudio surprisingly works with the qt5 from repositories and I can continue living. But the bug is strange. I still can't write cyrillyc in Neovim and Qt Creator